# Efficiently finding the indices of a sparse matrix's smallest columns

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

By "smallest column" I mean the column for which the sum of the elements is the least (i.e. most negative). Here is my attempt but it isn't very efficient because I build a whole list of the sums of the columns. `h` is a `scipy.sparse` matrix, `k` is the number of indices requested. It's not important that the result be sorted.

```
def indices_of_smallest_columns(h,k):
    size=h.get_shape()[0]
    arr=[h.tocsc().getcol(i).sum() for i in range(size)]
    return np.argpartition(arr,k)[:k]
```

Comment: How else can you get the smallest without finding all sums?

Comment: I should have been more precise. A list comprehension/for loop is never the way in such circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
In [2]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.2)
In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Your sum list:

```
In [5]: [M.tocsc().getcol(i).sum() for i in range(10)]
Out[5]: 
[1.5659425833256746,
 1.7665038140319338,
 0.0,
 0.6422706809316442,
 0.24922121199061487,
 1.439977730279475,
 0.17827454933565012,
 1.7955436609690185,
 0.4275656628694753,
 1.4029484081520989]
```

Getting the matrix sum directly:

```
In [6]: M.sum(axis=0)
Out[6]: 
matrix([[1.56594258, 1.76650381, 0.        , 0.64227068, 0.24922121,
         1.43997773, 0.17827455, 1.79554366, 0.42756566, 1.40294841]])
```

`sparse` uses matrix multiplication to get sums like this.

Timings:

```
In [7]: timeit [M.tocsc().getcol(i).sum() for i in range(10)]
2.87 ms ± 90.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [8]: timeit M.sum(axis=0)
161 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

If the matrix is already `csc`, times are even better:

```
In [12]: %%timeit h=M.tocsc()
    ...: h.sum(axis=0)
    ...: 
    ...: 
54.5 µs ± 1.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```